# How to prove this identity in vector calculus (suffix notation)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant, vector-analysis

Let $\epsilon_{ijk}$ be the alternating tensor defined by $$\epsilon_{ijk} = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if any of $i$, $j$, $k$ are equal}\\
1, &  \text{if $(i,j,k)=(1,2,3)$, $(2,3,1)$ or $(3,1,2)$}\\
-1, & \text{if $(i,j,k)=(1,3,2)$, $(2,1,3)$ or $(3,2,1)$}
\end{cases}
$$

While I know
$$|M|=\epsilon_{ijk}M_{1i}M_{2j}M_{3k}, \tag{*}\label{*}$$
I cannot answer the following question, which states:

> From \eqref{*}, derive that $\epsilon_{pqr} |M|=\epsilon_{ijk}M_{pi}M_{qj}M_{rk}$

Could someone give a proof using suffix notation please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some breadcrumbs...

The key ingredient is:  What happens to the determinant of a matrix when you swap two rows?  What is the determinant of a matrix that has repeated rows?

Say we start with a matrix $M$ and want to compute  $\epsilon_{ijk}M_{pi}M_{qj}M_{rk}$ (for $p,q,r$ distinct).  Let $\tilde{M}$ be the matrix obtained by sliding row $p$ of $M$ up to row $1$, row $q$ up to row $2$, and row $r$ up to row $3$.  Then $M_{pi}=\tilde{M}_{1i}$, etc.  Use (*) to compute $|\tilde{M}|$. How are $|M|$ and $|\tilde{M}|$ related?

The case where $p,q,r$ are not distinct is a consequence of the fact that a matrix with repeated rows has zero determinant.